# list access e[-1] is fine but e[1] is not in Python

Tags: python

In Python, I defined

```
string = ("car-automobile, gem-jewel, journey-voyage, boy-lad, coast-shore, "
          "asylum-madhouse, magician-wizard, midday-noon, furnacestove, food-fruit, "
          "bird-cock, bird-crane, tool-implement, brother-monk, ladbrother, "
          "crane-implement, journey-car, monk-oracle, cemetery-woodland, foodrooster, "
          "coast-hill, forest-graveyard, shore-woodland, monk-slave, coast-forest, "
          "lad-wizard, chord-smile, glass-magician, rooster-voyage, "
          "noon-string".split(', '))
test = [i.split('-') for i in string]
```

and the following code causes error:

```
[e[1] for e in test]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#136>", line 1, in <module>
    [e[1] for e in test]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but following code works

```
[e[-1] for e in test]
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few values with no `-` in them:

```
>>> [e for e in string if not '-' in e]
['furnacestove', 'ladbrother', 'foodrooster']
```

which when split results in a one-element list; there is only `e[0]`, no `e[1]`. `e[-1]` gives you the last element always, even if there is only 1.